# GetXVelocity returns wrong value

Tags: java, android

I have a view that move according to touch and I want to track the speed of which I move it, so I used `VelocityTracker` as shown below, but accoding to my log the speed is sometimes negative when I move my view from left to right and the opposite (the speed is sometimes positive when I move my view from right to left),
and I don't understand why.

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    int eid = event.getAction();
                    int index = event.getActionIndex();
                    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

                    switch (eid) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                            if (firstTouch)
                                offsetY = (int) (event.getRawY() - v.getY());
                            if (firstTouch)
                                offsetX = (int) (event.getRawX() - v.getX());

                            if(mVelocityTracker == null)
                                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                            else
                                mVelocityTracker.clear();
                            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);    
                            v.setX(event.getRawX() - offsetX);    
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

                            float velocity= VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(mVelocityTracker,pointerId);                            


// I print the speed and get the negative somtimes
                            Log.d("speed ","speed : "+speed );                           

                            firstTouch = true;

                            mVelocityTracker.recycle();
                            mVelocityTracker = null;

                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

anyone knows why this happens and how to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: whats wrong with negative velocity?

Comment: its wrong when i expect positive one, for example when i move the object from left to right

Comment: `"when I move my view from left to right and the opposite"` so what does `opposite` mean here? are you moving your finger from left to right all the time?

Comment: the opposite is when i move my finger from right to left and get positive velocity

Comment: so it smells like a bug, maybe you should follow `GestureDetector` or `ScrollView` sources on how they use `VelocityTracker`

Comment: I followed what I saw here: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/movement.html